# Create two jQuery plugins that can talk to each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-events, extends

My head is a mess right now. I want to create two jQuery plugins :

1. A tab plugin
2. A slider plugin.

This plugins has to talk to each other, for example, if I click on a tab, this tab will activate the correct index in the associated slider.
If i click on a slide, this will activate the correct tab too.

I started to create events listeners and triggers for that, when my tab was clicked, an event `tabChanged` is triggered, and in my slider plugin I'm listening to it.
But here is the trouble, my sliders can be loaded before my tabs, so the listeners is not attached correctly...

I tried to trigger another event on the document this time, called `tabsLoaded` and waiting for that response, it works but it start to be a bit confusing.

I was wondering if someone has a better solution for this ?
Tabs and sliders can work as standalone too, it might be possible to have only tabs without slider associated.

This is my tab plugin:

```js
(function($) {
  let pluginName = 'Tabs';

  function Tabs(element, options) {
    let settings = {};

    this.element = element;
    this.$element = $(this.element);
    this.settings = $.extend({}, settings, options);

    this.children = null;
    this.activeTabIndex = 0;
    this.nbTabs = 0;

    this.init();
  }

  $.extend(Tabs.prototype, {

    init: function() {
      this.children = this.$element.children();
      this.nbTabs = this.children.length;

      // Listeners
      this.children.on('click', {
        tabs: this
      }, this.onTabChange); // Click on a tab
      $(this).on('tabChange', this.setActive);

      // On Init, active the first tab
      if (this.children && this.nbTabs > 0) {
        $(this).trigger({
          type: 'tabChange',
          tab: this.children.first().index(),
        });
      }

      $(document).trigger({
        type: 'tabLoaded',
        tabs: this,
      });
    },
    setActive: function(event) {
      this.activeTabIndex = event.tab;
      this.children.eq(this.activeTabIndex).addClass('is-active');
    },
    onTabChange: function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const tabs = event.data.tabs;
      // Reset active classes
      tabs.children.removeClass('is-active');
      // Launch changeTab
      $(tabs).trigger({
        type: 'tabChange',
        tab: tabs.children.index(event.currentTarget),
      });
    }
  });

  $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      if (!$.data(this, pluginName)) {
        $.data(this, pluginName, new Tabs(this, options));
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.js-tabs').Tabs();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And this is my slider plugin listening to tabs :

```js
(function($) {
  let pluginName = 'Slider';

  function Slider(element, options) {
    let settings = {};

    this.element = element;
    this.$element = $(this.element);
    this.settings = $.extend({}, settings, options);

    this.id = null;
    this.tabs = null;
    this.children = null;
    this.activeSlideIndex = 0;
    this.nbSlides = 0;

    this.init();
  }

  $.extend(Slider.prototype, {

    init: function() {
      this.id = this.$element.attr('id');
      this.children = this.$element.children();
      this.nbSlides = this.children.length;
      // Listeners
      // Click on slide
      this.children.on('click', {
        slider: this
      }, this.onSlideChange);
      // On slide change
      $(this).on('slideChange', {
        slider: this
      }, this.onSlideChange);
      $(this).on('change', this.update);

      // On Init, active the first tab
      if (this.children && this.nbSlides > 0) {
        $(this).trigger({
          type: 'slideChange',
          slide: this.children.first().index(),
        });
      }
      $(document).trigger({
        type: 'sliderLoaded',
        slider: this,
      });
    },
    update: function() {
      // if Slider has an associated Tabs
      if (this.tabs) {
        $(this.tabs).on('tabChange', {
          slider: this
        }, this.onTabChange);
      }
    },
    onSlideChange: function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const slider = event.data.slider;
      const slide = event.slide;
      // Reset active classes
      slider.children.removeClass('is-active');
      slider.activeSlideIndex = slide ? slide : event.currentTarget;
      console.log(slider.activeSlideIndex);
      slider.children.eq(slider.activeSlideIndex).addClass('is-active');
    },
    // TABS
    onTabChange: function(event) {
      const slider = event.data.slider;
      const tabIndex = event.tab;
      if ($(slider.children).eq(tabIndex).length >= 0) {
        $(slider).trigger({
          type: 'slideChange',
          slide: tabIndex,
        });
      }
    }
  });

  $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      if (!$.data(this, pluginName)) {
        $.data(this, pluginName, new Slider(this, options));
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.js-slider').Slider();
});

// On Tabs loaded, insert it into slider
jQuery(document).on('tabLoaded', function(event) {
  const tabs = event.tabs;
  const sliderId = jQuery(tabs.element).data('slider-id');
  if (jQuery('#' + sliderId).first().data('Slider')) {
    const slider = jQuery('#' + sliderId).first().data('Slider');
    slider.tabs = tabs;
    slider.update();
  }
});
```

Comment: please post the event listeners and emitters you have tried

Comment: I have updated my post :)

Comment: I think, you should remove link between plugins (e.g. `onTabChange`).

`    $(function(){`
`      let $slider = $('.js-slider').Slider();`
`      let $tabs = $('.js-tabs').Tabs();`
`      $slider.on('changeSlide', function() { $tabs.Slider('select', 'first') });`
`      $tabs.on('changeTab', function() { $slider.Tabs('select', 'another')};`
`    });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed @Anton's advices and i split my tabs and sliders and it's working nice :)

- First, i removed my plugins' inits from plugins' files.
- Then i put every inits into another file that i called "app.js"

My App.js looks like this :

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    let $sliders = $('.js-slider').Slider();
    let $tabs = $('.js-tabs').Tabs();

    $sliders.on('slideChanged', function (event) {
        const sliderId = $(this).attr('id');
        const slide = event.slide;
        $tabs.filter('[data-slider-id=' + sliderId + ']').data('Tabs').select(slide);
    });

    $tabs.on('tabChanged', function (event) {
        const sliderId = $(this).data('slider-id');
        const tab = event.tab;
        $sliders.filter('#' + sliderId).data('Slider').select(tab);
    });
});
```

I'm listening every events sent like 'slideChanged', or 'tabChanged' then i get the right tabs or slider instance by their matching IDs.

Here my code for tabs :

```js
(function($) {
  let pluginName = 'Tabs';

  function Tabs(element, options) {
    let settings = {};

    this.element = element;
    this.$element = $(this.element);
    this.settings = $.extend({}, settings, options);

    this.children = null;
    this.activeTabIndex = 0;
    this.nbTabs = 0;

    this.init();
  }

  $.extend(Tabs.prototype, {

    init: function() {
      this.children = this.$element.children();
      this.nbTabs = this.children.length;

      // Listeners
      this.children.on('click', {
        tabs: this
      }, this.onTabClick); // Click on a tab
      $(this).on('tabChanged', this.onTabClick);

      // On Init, active the first tab
      if (this.children && this.nbTabs > 0) {
        this.children.first().click();
      }
    },
    select: function(tab) {
      // Reset active classes
      this.children.removeClass('is-active');
      this.activeTabIndex = tab;
      this.children.eq(tab).addClass('is-active');
    },
    onTabClick: function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const tabs = event.data.tabs;
      const tab = tabs.children.index(event.currentTarget);
      tabs.select(tab);
      // Launch changeTab
      $(tabs.element).trigger({
        type: 'tabChanged',
        tab: tab,
      });
    }
  });

  $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      if (!$.data(this, pluginName)) {
        $.data(this, pluginName, new Tabs(this, options));
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

and slider :

```js
(function($) {
  let pluginName = 'Slider';

  function Slider(element, options) {
    let settings = {};

    this.element = element;
    this.$element = $(this.element);
    this.settings = $.extend({}, settings, options);

    this.id = null;
    this.tabs = null;
    this.children = null;
    this.activeSlideIndex = 0;
    this.nbSlides = 0;

    this.init();
  }

  $.extend(Slider.prototype, {

    init: function() {
      this.id = this.$element.attr('id');
      this.children = this.$element.children();
      this.nbSlides = this.children.length;
      // Listeners
      // Click on slide
      this.children.on('click', {
        slider: this
      }, this.onSlideClick);
      // On slide change
      $(this).on('slideChanged', this.onSlideClick);

      // On Init, active the first tab
      if (this.children && this.nbSlides > 0) {
        this.children.first().click();
      }
    },
    select: function(slide) {
      // Reset active classes
      this.children.removeClass('is-active');
      this.activeSlideIndex = slide;
      this.children.eq(this.activeSlideIndex).addClass('is-active');
    },
    onSlideClick: function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const slider = event.data.slider;
      const slide = slider.children.index(event.currentTarget);
      slider.select(slide);
      // Launch changeTab
      $(slider.element).trigger({
        type: 'slideChanged',
        slide: slide,
      });
    },
  });

  $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      if (!$.data(this, pluginName)) {
        $.data(this, pluginName, new Slider(this, options));
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```